# Reuse a jQuery selector instead of constructing it twice?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Just starting out with jQuery. I've ended up with some ugly code here to dynamically change the background on various regions of a world map. I'm constructing the same selector twice for the `mouseover` and `mouseout`. (That's what the `hover` does: combine the two... yes?) Is there a cleaner way to do this? That is, only build it once and be able to use for both?

```
$('.regionName').hover(  
  function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    id = (id.substring(0, 2));
    var region = "#" + id + "BG";
    $(region).css('background', 'url(images/world-map-' + id + '.png) no-repeat');
  },
  function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    id = (id.substring(0, 2));
    var region = "#" + id + "BG";
    $(region).css('background', 'none');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.regionName').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    var id = this.id.substring(0, 2);
    $("#" + id + "BG").css('background', e.type==='mouseenter'?'url(images/world-map-' + id + '.png) no-repeat':'none');
});
```

From the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

> Calling $(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut) is shorthand for:
>
> $(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that `.css` method, create a custom class and use `.toggleClass()`. You can then combine both of your functions into one:

```
$('.regionName').hover(  
  function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    id = (id.substring(0, 2));
    var region = "#" + id + "BG";
    $(region).toggleClass('addbg-'+id); // add on mouseover, remove on mouseout
  }
);
```

Now add all the relevant `.addbg-<whatever>` classes to your stylesheet, and you're good to go.

Comment: What if he has a hundreds of ids? The stylesheet would be really long

Comment: You are correct. However, OP hasn't said one way or the other.

Comment: I know, but in my opinion, that doesn't matter, we have to provide long term solutions and abstract concepts to point people in the right direction. Solving just because 'its the right answer' or because 'it works' might generate risks. And if we are aware of those risks, they have to be mentioned. Personally, I like your solution though :) that's an approach I would have gone as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making compact code, I prefer readability:

```
$('.regionName').hover(  
    function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        regionHelper(id);
});

//performs the toggle
function regionHelper(id){
     id = id.substring(0, 2);
     var region = "#" + id + "BG";
     var element = $('#' + id);
     if (element.css('background').length == 0){
        element.css('background', 'url(images/world-map-' + id + '.png) no-repeat');
     } else {
        element.css('background', '');
     }
}
```